# UNIQUE constraint failed: EMPLOYEE.Employee_ID

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table EMPLOYEE(
Employee_ID int primary key,
Last_name varchar(30),
First_Name varchar(20),
CellPhone char(15),
ExperienceLevel varchar(30),
CONSTRAINT CHK_EMPLOYEE_EXPERIENCELEVEL CHECK (ExperienceLevel IN('Master', 'Junior ', 'Senior'))
);
```

When I insert this into my table database error pops up

```
insert into employee values 
('E5'    ,  'John'     ,  'Cokie'     ,   '121-111-1111' , 'Mastery');
```

Comment: Always list the target columns in `INSERT` statements!

Comment: That means you already have an employee with ID `E5`.

Comment: Is the name really Cokie John, not John Cokie?

Comment: The posted data will not  give a unique constraint failure. Attempting to store 'E5' in an integer column would give either "ORA-01722: invalid number" or an "ORA-06502:  numeric or value error". :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's the constraint that fails, but a different possible issue that I noticed is that the Employee_ID field is an int but you're storing a string ('E5'). If there's no duplicate record in the table then the error should disappear.

Comment: Hey Mboya, I changed my int into str, thanks for pointing that out